# a way to improve performance speed/quality on my optaplanner job shop scheduling project

Tags: java, drools, scheduling, job-scheduling, optaplanner

We are working on a job shop scheduling with `optaplanner` and drools.
We are trying to manage a schedule similar to the leveling of projects on Microsoft project management. In particular, given that more resources can be over-allocated, it is necessary to establish on which resources to act or to give an ordered list of priorities. Microsoft Project uses the flexibility margin. So first move the activities that have a higher margin.

We need to obtain the same results we have from Microsoft project management from `optaplanner` especially as regard time performance In our scheduling, the problem is that there are more gaps in the work centers compared to project management and there is a delay in the makespan.

We noticed that the scheduler works better than the project management with `100 jobs` and anticipates the last processing by 5 days, while from `600 jobs` upwards it is worse and we don't know if this is due to some drolls rules that are not exact or by the custom move.

From when the custom move was created, even if there was a considerable saving of time for the hard constraints, the processes, grouped by order, are always "attached" to each other which in itself is not wrong but that could limit `optaplanner` in fact project management makes more joints For us, planning must be fast and speed performance is one of our first goals.

In a set of `70 machines` with `4000 jobs`, we need be able to schedule optimally in a few minutes.

**Domain model**
classes and planning entities are:

1. work centers (id, name, calendar ref)
2. calendar (id, shifts)
3. shifts (weekday number, start/end time)
4. processes (id, name, duration, start date, order)
5. order (id, name, start / end)
6. assignment (id, working ref, work center, start and end date)
7. scheduling (list of every single previous point + score )

**Constraints**

```
-   hard
   production sequences:   
    a process cannot start before its previous one ends
   valid calendar:
    a process must be assigned in the working shifts of the machine in which it is processed
   overload:
    example: if on Monday the machine works 8 hours. I can't put two “5-hour” jobs on it
```

```
-   soft
   makespan
   do not leave holes of inactivity when using the center
```

For the soft constraint, we are considering only the orders delay trying to minimize it. Not considering any other logical critical path.
Our problem fact is a range of big decimals, where the whole part represents the day, the decimal part hours and minutes

The assignment class is our planning entity, where the starting date is our genuine variable and end date is our shadow variable (depending on duration)

We have also implemented a custom move that moves the subsequent workings of the work chosen and moved and by the scheduler. This is because it took too long (even half an hour) to resolve the hard constraints, instead of with this custom move it takes less than 30 seconds.

To get faster results we used `contablevaluerange` as a problem fact, a custom move and transformed shift from objects to a calendar. 
example:

**BEFORE**

```
   object1 17 July from 8 to 14;
   object2: 17 July from 15 to 19;
   object3 18 July from 8 to 14, 
   etc etc
```

**AFTER**
now they are simply a calendar on which controls for the constraints are made and moreover iterators have been used to generate the random moves (before they were used lists)

Now we are comparing `optaplanner` results with Microsoft project results. 
Comparing with Microsoft project (same problem dataset with 700 jobs) there is a month of delay in our planner, we explain better:

```
   project management  
     starts the first processing on 17 July 2019 and the last on 7 May 2020
   optaplanner
     starts the first processing on 17 July 2019 and the last on half of June 2020.
```

The time taken `optaplanner` to define the dates are three minutes.

Comment: TLDR, but do [read this blog post](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2016/02/12/WhatIsTheBottleneckInMySolver.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: We are trying to manage a scheduler similar to the leveling of projects on Microsoft project management.
We need to obtain the same results we have from Microsoft project management from optaplanner especially as regard time performance.
In a set of 70 machines with 4000 jobs, we need be able to schedule optimally in a few minutes.
We are using 6 planning entities. 3 Hard and 2 Soft constraints are accounted by Optaplanner.
Does anybody done this before ?

Comment: Yes, I 've seen many of such cases - and been involved in fixing scaling bottlenecks if any in a number of those. If performance/scaling is an issue, start with running optaplanner-benchmark and following that blog post.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. We have used benchmark but without success, is it possible for you to give us specific paided consultancy ?

Comment: For consultancy, contact Red Hat, see "services" on optaplanner.org. What exception does the benchmarker throw?

Comment: Thank You, it does not throw exceptions. The problem is that we don't know how to implement CPM and if this is possible. I tried more times to contact Red HAT but without success.

Comment: I 've forward the reference internally - they 'll contact you soon - and we're looking into what went wrong. Thanks for letting me know.